# launchd exit status "-9"

Tags: launchd, rsync

I have a couple of launchd jobs starting a rsync wrapper script. They have been running fine for at least 3 years, but now most of them fail with exit status -9. All jobs are configured like this (with different rbackup.py parameters):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.snafu.rs1_core</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python3</string>
        <string>/Users/snafu/Library/Scripts/rbackup.py</string>
        <string>rs1_core</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>7</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/snafu/Library/Logs/launchd.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/snafu/Library/Logs/launchd.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The `launchd.log` file does not contain any hint, and 2 out of 10 jobs still run fine. When I start the rsync wrapper with the respective parameters, it works, too. How can I debug this phenomenon?

Comment: Where do you see the exit status? What is the exact text you see there? Is there anything in the logs at all? Can you extend the wrapper (`rbackup.py`) to write a log entry immediately at the beginning so we know whether the script gets started at all?

Comment: Also, did you update python or a python library recently?

Comment: This sound similar to the few questions we’ve received about processes getting the “KILLED -9” error.  First, did you migrate from Intel to Silicon?  Second, do the scripts work if you manually run them?

Comment: @allan The "2 out of 10 jobs run fine" part is interesting here (and the wrapper seems to work anyway, see last sentences).

Comment: The wrapper may not be architecture specific while the contents might be.  We also don’t know *when* the scripts were created; 8 out of 10 may have been migrated and those 2 are “new”.

Comment: Also, I am curious to know if SSH works properly or if it also gets killed.

Comment: Re "how to debug": [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337513/how-can-i-debug-a-launchd-script-that-doesnt-run-on-startup)

Comment: Problem solved: It was related to the macOS security mechanism, and I had to manually start one of the launchd jobs to grant the required permissions. It is still beyond me why 2 of the jobs ran *without* having these permissions. Sorry for the noise, and thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Good to hear. Can you post the steps taken as an answer below and accept it? Other might have the same issue and would benefit from an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by starting the jobs manually (once):

```
launchctl start net.snafu.rs1_core
```

It is still unclear why 2 jobs were not affected.